# Hydrostatics and vapors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

In the picture below we initially have water vapors and air.
We then introduce the tube in the water vase till half of its lenght.
We know P0(atmospheric pressure), l, a and p(density of water).
[image]

We are given to find the pressure of the water vapors.

I have equaled the pressures from the surface of water in the tube and the surface in the water and got $$ P_{0} + \rho g a = p_{s}+p_{air}$$
I still don't know what to do with the pressure of the air.
I have tried thinking that there is an izotherm between the intitial and final states and initially the air pressure is P0 and since the temperature is constant and also Ps is constant (considering that the liquefaction adds negligible mass of water).
Though my answer is not the same and I do not have a solution.

The answer to this problem is :$$P_{s}=P_{0}- \rho g a \frac{l+2a}{l-2a}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation applies to the second diagram. I recommend that you write a similar equation for the first diagram. But don't forget that the air pressures will be different in the two cases, but related by Boyle's law, whereas the saturated vapour pressure will be the same. I can confirm that, using these ideas, we do get the answer you have quoted.

Comment: Thanks, I got it right.